# How can I save my curry - it's way too oily!

Tags: oil, slow-cooking, curry

I cooked a chicken curry in the slowcooker last night, I came down this morning and its way too oily.  I think because of this the coconut milk has separated a little too.

Any way I can save this, even a little?

Thankyou

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Allow it to cool, then put it in the fridge for a few hours. The fat should rise to the top and harden, making it easier to scoop away.

If you can't wait for it to cool, either skim the oil off with a spoon or use some kitchen paper to soak it up.

Comment: oooh Thankyou! I will definitely try that tonight! :D